# Capoing a dulcimer changes the mode - what does this mean for me practically?

Tags: capos

I have a "woodrow instrument", which is a diatonically fretted dulcimer you play like a guitar.

When getting it from the maker he said "Here's something cool, if you capo the instrument you get a different mode." I know there are 7 modes, and that generally they are associated with certain feelings in the music, but I don't know how to use that information. Is it as simple as, learn a song, capo, play the song as written and it will sound different? Or is it that different songs will be available to me?

This is not my main instrument but I would like to use the opportunity to learn as much as I can about the music theory of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'You play like a guitar'. Well, yes and no!

The guitar part involves the plucking, which is similar to how a guitar may be plucked.

***However***, the fretting is rather different from a guitar. (Hence this re-answering!).

A dulcimer is not fretted like a guitar, where each fret is a semitone from the next, when pressed down. Looking at a dulcimer's fretboard, there are several frets missing!

That's because each fret is in its particular place to make a major diatonic scale as it goes towards the bridge.

It's a bit like leaving out frets 1, 3, 6, 8 and 10. Putting in only the frets which provide the seven notes on a major scale, the eighth being half way along the fingerboard, just where the 12 fret of a guitar would be.

So, saying that putting a capo on the first fret on a dulcimer is similar to playing the notes from there up as a Dorian scale instead of the Ionian (major) from open. Put that capo on fret 2, and play up a fret at a time - you have Phrygian mode. It makes sense not to try changing to another string at any point. Let's face it - with effectively three strings, tunes a P5 apart, it wouldn't work too well anyway.

Therefore, it could be construed that each fret position is making a different mode available. Open = Ionian, 1st - Dorian, 2nd = Phrygian, 4th = Lydian, 5th = Mixolydian etc. And wherever the capo iss, is root.

Comment: Would E Dorian and F Dorian count as the same mode or different modes, then?

Comment: "play like a guitar" was a reference to the fact that unlike a mountain/lap dulcimer, the "woodrow" specifically is played against the body oriented like a guitar. What you are saying echoes what the maker said. Still leaves my question of, what can I do with this information? "Is it as simple as, learn a song, capo, play the song as written and it will sound different? Or is it that different songs will be available to me? "

Comment: @Dekkadeci - assume a string is tuned open to note D. Put capo on fret 1, and you have the remaining frets constituting E Dorian. Capo fret 2, and it's F# Phrygian, if that helps. You couldn't play F Dorian with that tuning!

Comment: @Ben - given that you know how Dorian (for example) works, and you wanted to play a tune in that particular mode, you'd capo fret 1, and that note will be your root. Tune the string to D, you would have E Dorian mode as you go up and down the 'board. Merely transposing a melody into a mode *can* work, but that's not really the essence of modes. Certain songs are in certain modes, so if you wanted to play a song that was in, say, Lydian, then you'd put capo on fret 3. Then all the remaining frets would 'belong' to that mode.

Answer (score 1):

What are the strings tuned to?

If it is DAd, then using no capo, ie open strings, you'll be playing in D Mixolydian (not D Major). If you put a capo on Fret 1, you'll be playing in E minor; if using a Capo at Fret 3 you'll be playing in G major. If capo is at fret 4, you'll be playing in A Dorian.
The letter gives you the root note (and therefore the name) of the key. The word after the letter tells you the mode or shape of that key's scale ~ which is all about how the tones and semi-tones are sequenced. (Each mode has its own characteristic sequence, which gives a mode it's distinct feel).

You can feel this if you run through a Major (= Ionian mode) scale, then run through the minor (= Aeolian mode) scale, with both having the same root note, eg D).

Typically, traditional tunes are written in a 7-note modal scale.  Most Dulcimer tunes are written in Mixolydian, or Aeolian (that is another name for a minor scale), with some in Dorian, and some in Ionian (that last one is another term for a Major Scale).

Because the Dulcimer is not chromatic, (i.e. it does not have all 12 possible notes as, say, a piano does), it is limited to 1 Major scale, 1 minor scale, 1 Dorian scale, and 1 Mixolydian scale, determined by which fret you apply a Capo to, and the notes the open strings are tuned to. So as well as knowing the root note of a tune (it's usually the last note played), you need to establish its mode to know if it can be played on the Dulcimer in its particular tuning.

Some sources which may help you get more understanding of this are:

[Stephen Smith on Modes and MD tuned to DAd](https://sksmithmusic.com/the-virtual-classroom/modes-and-the-mountain-dulcimer/)

[Bonnie Carol on Keys, Modes & tunings for MD](https://www.bearmeadow.com/smi/modes.htm)

[Musicfolk on modes and tunings for MD](https://musicfolk.com/2004/03/18/modes-and-tunings-for-the-mountain-dulcimer/)

A search on the web will provide insights into modes (not specifically for, but still relevant to Dulcimer), including some great demos on Youtube.

Happy Exploring,